# SSL Requests made with cURL fail after process fork

Tags: php, ssl, curl, centos, fork

I have run into some pretty strange behaviour with curl

1. If I make an SSL request using curl in the parent process and then
   fork the process and try to make another SSL request in the child
   process the attempt fails with error no. 35 (SSL connect error).
2. If I do not make the SSL request in the parent, the one in the child process succeeds.
3. I can make any number of non SSL requests in the parent and SSL requests in the child succeed.

It appears that this is a bug in libcurl [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466809/libcurl-ssl-error-after-fork) and the answerer has a [work around for it](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/curl_global_cleanup/osx-10.3.php).

My questions are:

1. Is [curl_global_cleanup](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/curl_global_cleanup/osx-10.3.php) exposed by some other name in the PHP API?
2. If not is there some other work around?

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.google.ca/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$success = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($success !== false); // true
curl_close($ch); 

$pid = pcntl_fork();

if ($pid === 0) {
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.google.ca/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $success = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($success !== false); // true
    curl_close($ch);

    $ch = curl_init('https://www.google.ca/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $success = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($success !== false); // false

    $errno = curl_errno($ch); // 35
    $error = curl_error($ch); // SSL connect error
    curl_close($ch);
} else if ($pid > 0) {
    // wait for child process
    pcntl_wait($status);
} else {
    // handel fork error
}
```

If this is not a bug with libcurl and it is something I am doing wrong please let me know.

Comment: wouldn't surprise me if curl's using the process PID in its prng seeds. forking will change the pid, changing the seed, which fundamentally changes all of the randomish numbers being generated.

Comment: @Marc B, It could be the case, I haven't found any documentation to that effect though. Actually I haven't found any documentation on this issue.

Comment: Seems you're not the only one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466809/libcurl-ssl-error-after-fork … btw, why don't you use `curl_multi`?

Comment: @lxg, Yes I know about that question, I have a link to it in the question. The example in the question is paired down to just the heart of the problem. There are other asynchronous tasks that must be performed in the child as well as the second curl call.

Comment: @robbmj: Oops, didn't see the link, sorry.

Comment: @lxg, no worries. I thought twice about posting the question, but ultimately decided to post as a work around exists in C but the PHP cURL API does not expose the `curl_global_cleanup` function.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this by using the [pcntl_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php) function. So you would essentially remove your child code and place it in a different php file which then gets executed in (and actually replaces) the child process.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.google.ca/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$success = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($success !== false); // true
curl_close($ch); 

$pid = pcntl_fork();

if ($pid === 0) {
  pcntl_exec('child_curl.php');
} else if ($pid > 0) {
  // wait for child process
  pcntl_wait($status);
} else {
  // handel fork error
}
```

Contents of child_curl.php:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.ca/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$success = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($success !== false); // true
curl_close($ch);

$ch = curl_init('https://www.google.ca/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$success = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($success !== false); // false

$errno = curl_errno($ch); // 35
$error = curl_error($ch); // SSL connect error
curl_close($ch);
```

After the execution of the child you will not see an error.

These other issues helped me out:

- [libCurl SSL error after fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466809/libcurl-ssl-error-after-fork?lq=1)
- [Curl and pcntl_fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901910/curl-and-pcntl-fork?lq=1)

Comment: This is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to directly deal with the issue out lined in the question. However, I have developed a couple of workarounds. Both solve the process fork problem with (guess what) another fork.

**Please note:** This is not intended to be any kind of performance improvement. It is simply a workaround for the issue highlighted in the question.

```
function fetch_page($page) {
    $tmp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'curl_tmp_file');
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid === 0) {
        $ch = curl_init($page);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($content) {
            file_put_contents($tmp_file, $content);
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else if ($pid > 0) {
        pcntl_wait($status);
        $content = false;
        if (pcntl_wexitstatus($status) === 0) {
            $content = file_get_contents($tmp_file);
        }
        unlink($tmp_file);
        return $content;
    }
    else {
        unlink($tmp_file);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Letter on I can make https connections in a child process.

```
fetch_page('https://www.google.ca/');

$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid === 0) {   
    $ch = curl_init('https://www.google.ca/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $success = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($success !== false); // true
} else if ($pid > 0) {
    // wait for child process
    pcntl_wait($status);
} else {
    // handel fork error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to use sockets.

```
function fetch_page($url) {
    $socketPair = array();
    if (socket_create_pair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, $socketPair) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid === 0) {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        socket_close($socketPair[1]);
        socket_set_nonblock($socketPair[0]);
        $exitStatus = $content ? 0 : 1;
        if ($content) {
            while ((strlen($content) > 0) && ($wrote = socket_write($socketPair[0], $content))) {
                $content = substr($content, $wrote);
            }
        }
        socket_close($socketPair[0]);
        exit($exitStatus);
    }
    else if ($pid > 0) {
        pcntl_wait($status);
        socket_close($socketPair[0]);
        $content = false;
        if (pcntl_wexitstatus($status) === 0) {
            $content = '';
            while ($line = socket_read($socketPair[1], 4096)) {
                $len = strlen($content);
                $content .= $line;
            }
        }
        socket_close($socketPair[1]);
        return $content;
    }
    socket_close($socketPair[0]);
    socket_close($socketPair[1]);
    return false;
}
```